# PHP PDO syntax error

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

can you please what is the problem with this code ?

```
$host = "localhost";
$database = "dbname";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "password";

$inf = "information_schema";
$db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname={$database};host={$host};port=5432", $username, $password);
!$db && exit("Database connect failed");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$handle = fopen("code.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $array = array();
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        preg_match("/(.*?)\s\((.*?)\)/i", $line, $match);
        $query = "INSERT INTO combo (group,html,value) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $s = $db->prepare($query);
        $s->bindParam(1, $group);
        $s->bindParam(2, $html);
        $s->bindParam(3, $value);
        $group = "state";
        $html = $match[1];
        $value = $match[2];
        $s->execute();
    }
    var_dump($array);
}
```

i am getting this error. i also tried for param name like :html,:value but this is not working and giving the same error.

pelase tell what is the problem with this

[image]

Comment: `group` is a reserved word in sql, use `\`group\``.

Comment: Please describe your table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GROUP
```

is a reserved word
Please see here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html
You can use

```
`group`
```

Comment: ok good . now it is working